# I can't deploy a community Ubuntu docker image to Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azure-container-instances

I run the following Azure CLI command:

```
az container create --resource-group Experimental --name my-sage
 --image sagemath/sagemath-jupyter --ip-address public --ports 8888
```

and get the following error

> The OS type 'null' of image 'sagemath/sagemath-jupyter' does not
>   match the OS type 'Linux' of container group 'my-sage'.

Even though the sagemath image is built on Ubuntu Xenial image: https://github.com/sagemath/docker-images

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Azure Container instance does not support this image. You could try to create this image on Azure Portal, you will get same error log.

[image]

Please check this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-overview).

Azure Container Instances is a great solution for any scenario that can operate in isolated containers, including simple applications, task automation, and build jobs.

For your scenario, I suggest you could use [Azure Container Service(aks)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/index).

Comment: Shengbao, thanks for your response. I already knew the previous response was wrong because I tried it myself and got error. I also know it will likely work on AKS, but ACI is simpler solution for occasional use of this docker image.So now I have a further question, for which I don't know where to find the answer in the documentation link you sent.: since I have access to the source of this image in github, what change could I make that would allow it to work on ACI?
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The `--os-type` should default to Linux, if for some reason yours is not you can set the OS Type on the command.

```
az container create --resource-group Experimental --name my-sage
 --image sagemath/sagemath-jupyter --ip-address public --ports 8888 --os-type Linux
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is wrong. The default value is Linux, even you add it, you will get some error log.